# Adding a custom navigation bar covering content in screen

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have added a custom navigation bar via storyboard. I was expecting the content on the screen to automatically shift downward. but instead it completely covers content on the top of the screen.. is there a clean line of code that automatically creates that spacing between the navigation bar and the view itself?

Comment: show your code, how you added custom Nav bar

Comment: easy way out set the top constraint to 84 64 for navigation bar and 20 for Status Bar

Answer (score 1):

You might have heard about Cocpods which i feel is a better way to go for cutsom Navigation bar.
You just need to implement the protocol and give the specifications you need for the Navigation bar
Go through the following cooped

https://cocoapods.org/pods/resizable-navigation-bar

Answer (score 0):

Just call this method from viewDidLoad :

```
func createNavBar() {

        let leftNavigationButton =  UIButton()
        leftNavigationButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_back.png"), forState: .Normal)
        leftNavigationButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 15)
        leftNavigationButton.addTarget(self, action: "onBackButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        let customBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: leftNavigationButton)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;

        //set TitleAppIcon
        let GR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("headerLogoTapAction:"))
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 90, y: 0, width: ((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width)/3), height: 40))
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        let image = UIImage(named: "yourimag.png") //or set title 
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(GR)
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        navigationItem.titleView = imageView
    }
```

Hope this gonna help you